# Counting 2d lists in python

Tags: python, list, loops, multidimensional-array

How can I count the number of items that are 'hit' in this 2d list??

```
grid = [['hit','miss','miss','hit','miss'],
     ['miss','miss','hit','hit','miss'],
     ['miss','miss','miss','hit','hit'],
     ['miss','miss','miss','hit','miss'],
     ['hit','miss','miss','miss','miss']]

battleships = 0
for i in grid:
    if i == "hit":
    battleships = battleships + 1
print battleships
```

I know that code is wrong, but it gives an idea of what I want to do I hope??

thanks

Comment: `if i == "hit":`   is wrong, `i` is a list

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [`list.count`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange):

```
>>> ['hit','miss','miss','hit','miss'].count('hit')
2

>>> grid = [['hit','miss','miss','hit','miss'],
...      ['miss','miss','hit','hit','miss'],
...      ['miss','miss','miss','hit','hit'],
...      ['miss','miss','miss','hit','miss'],
...      ['hit','miss','miss','miss','miss']]
>>> [row.count('hit') for row in grid]
[2, 2, 2, 1, 1]
```

And [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum):

```
>>> sum(row.count('hit') for row in grid)
8
```

Comment: can you explain why [row.count('hit') for row in grid] is within brackets? also, how is this counting within the nested lists? i.e., if I wrote print grid.count("hit"), why doesn't that count through all the lists? I know I can write something like grid[1].count which will count within the second list, but how is your code accessing the contents of all the nested lists?

Comment: @user2212774, It's [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). 'list.count' does not search nested list. It only match its items.

Answer (score 2):

If I had code that used 2D lists quite a bit, I would make a generator that returns each element in a 2D list:

```
def all_elements_2d(l):
    for sublist in l:
        for element in sublist:
            yield element
```

And then you can do other things with it, like count all the 'hit' strings:

```
hits = sum(element == 'hit' for element in all_elements_2d(grid))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Transaction=[['Mango','Onion','Jar','Key-chain','Eggs','Chocolates'],
['Nuts','Onion','Jar','Key-chain','Eggs','Chocolates'],
['Mango','Apple','Key-chain','Eggs'],
['Mango','Toothbrush','corn','Key-chain','Chocolates'],
['corn','Onion','Key-chain','Knife','Chocolates']
]
count1=[['Mango',0],['Onion',0],['Jar',0],['Key-chain',0],['Eggs',0],
['Chocolates',0],['Nuts',0],['Apple',0],['Toothbrush',0],['corn',0],['Knife',0]]
for j in range(0,10):
 x=0
for i in range(0,5):
 x=x+Transaction[i].count(count1[j][0]);
count1[j][1]=x
print count1
```

Comment: you should explain the code, add some text along with it, not just post it like that.